# How to debug javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have the following code to find a bug in:

```
function something(callback) {
  somethingElse(function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
    callback(null, res);
  });
}

something(function(err, res){
  console.log(err,res);
});

//something else defined elsewhere
```

Where should I begin with? I looked for syntax and things look okay and also tried jsHint to look for some obvious problems that it might catch. Where should I begin with and what concepts should I use?

Comment: Try the Developer Console?

Comment: Indentation, notes, log each step and if a step isn't logged usually means that's where it broke. Also don't use shorthand conditions of you're just beginning.

Comment: Developer Console will give the error that somethingElse is not defined and I don't have the actual implementation of somethingElse to use

Comment: @Arihant: Well, if `somethingElse` is not defined, then you found the bug.  You need to define a function in order to use it.

Comment: Where is `something` defined?  Where is `somethingElse`?  What is the context of this code?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's an issue of score.  `somethingElse` is not available within the scope of `something`.  Possibly adding `.bind(this)` to the end of `something` will solve the issue, if `somethingElse` is defined in that same scope.

```
function something(callback) {
  somethingElse(function(err, res) {
  if (err) callback(err);
  callback(null, res);
  });
}.bind(this)

something(function(err, res){
  console.log(err,res);
});

//something else defined elsewhere
```

If you could show us more code, specifically where `somethingElse` is defined, that will help us help you

Answer (score -1):

This first thing you should do is check the Developer Console. Chrome debug window shown in the below picture.

Putting console.log in the code to simulate a breakpoint is the easiest way to debug in Javascript.

Once thing to beware of when you are using asynchronous functions is the `this` pointer, it could easily be pointing to a different scope. use `.bind(this)` after an async function will force the `this` pointer inside async pointing to

[image]